# Swift - Passing a string from VC1 to VC2 - Crash

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift

I have a app in swift where I'm just trying to pass a string from one ViewController to another. After the segue,  I see the second viewController on top of the first, the data is passed, and I get the following exception:

```
2014-07-11 10:58:17.078 Flipper[8967:377257] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtC7Flipper19FirstViewController textField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fba2351eda0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c805055 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e528a1c objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c80bf1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c764dbc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c764958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010d2ed196 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010d3f1c80 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d9fbb86 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 256
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d45cbff -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 117
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d9fb98f -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 114
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d355722 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree] + 161
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d355bdd __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 76
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d35594c -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 91
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d3ef12c __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke478 + 785
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d3eb7bd -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 87
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010d3edd8e __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 133
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010da1d123 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 110
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010d3e8ea3 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1120
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010d34542a -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 209
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010d345760 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 76
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d176f9e _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 308
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ea64d64 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ea50f82 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 941
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c76dae9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c73046b __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c72fa06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001103b9abf GSEventRunModal + 161
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010d2ebcf8 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    28  Flipper                             0x000000010c37737d top_level_code + 77
    29  Flipper                             0x000000010c3773ba main + 42
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ea99145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My VC1 code is:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField
    var myVariable:String!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "P1ToP2") {
            var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as SecondViewController;
            myVariable = textField.text
            svc.myVariable = myVariable
        }
    }
}
```

My VC2 code is:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var labelTwo: UILabel
    var myVariable:String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        labelTwo.text = myVariable
    }
```

I'm using a Storyboard where VC1 has a Button that invokes a Show (push) segue called P1ToP2

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Is that all the code for VC2?

Comment: Yes. This is of course, a test app... Just learning.

Comment: You got me thinking. There was no extra code in VC2, but there was an IBAction listed in the storyboard. Deleting that solved the problem.. So thanks.. +1

Answer (score 1):

As your crash says:
    `reason: '-[_TtC7Flipper19FirstViewController textField:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
and you have not mentioned that the crash occurs on clicking the button.

My guess is try remove the space between `textField:` and `UITextField`.

I guess the problem is there, not in passing the string.

Comment: How could you tell clicking a button caused the crash?

Comment: I am not telling that, I am justifying that he has not mentioned this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it does not resolve the issue. As for clicking the button, after that, as I did state, I see the second VC - it's overlaid on the first. Then the crash occurs.. +1 for trying :)

Comment: Its definitely something to do with the use of the textField. If I remove references to it in both VCs, the crash does not recur.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte you should try using a label once, if label.text also produces the same error. It has to be something in textField.text then.